# How to prevent VM images in VMWare workstation from going to suspension mode?

Tags: virtual-machine, sleep

I have an exe file which needs to be running on the VMs (win7 and win8 VM images) on VMWarestation 9.

The exe usually runs for more than 3 hours, so I need to make sure the VM is not going to suspension mode within the 3 hours.

I have disabled the screensaver mode and sleep mode from the Control Panel of the VM images, and also I disabled the screensaver and sleep mode on the host machine which is running the workstation.

But, the VM images still go to the suspension mode within the 3 hours, in that case, I cannot have the exe finishing running.

Does anyone know how to prevent the VM image from going to suspension mode please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried going into 'Power Options' and selecting 'High Performance' then going to 'Change plan settings', 'Change advanced power settings'

Comment: hi  twoleggedhorse, Thank you for the quick response. This is the VMWare Workstation 9 I'm using . I can't find the high performance setting, instead, there is a "power control", in which, there are a "suspend" and "suspend guest" options.   Or maybe I go to the wrong place.

Comment: You need to log on to the guest VM and type 'Power Options' (without the quotes) into the start menu.

Comment: Although most likely not the case here, I had this problem when the Anti Virus on a VM did an automated scan and was set to sleep on scan completion - took me ages to figure that one out.

Comment: I think I found the reason: in the EXE file, I run a command to stop sleep and screen saver , but it seems it doesn't work, that's why it goes to the suspension mode. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: hi  twoleggedhorse, I noticed that if I manually set the screensaver and sleep mode setting to be 5 hours via Control Panel inside the VM, and I run my exe app(which lasts for about 3 hours), the exe app seems be hanging if I leave the VM with app running without touching it. Do  you have any idea about why this happens?

Comment: Try disabling the VMWare Tools service on the guest VM, could also try this: In VMWARE tools go under the scripts tab, and you will see a script event that probably says 'Suspend Guest operating system'. Untoggle 'Use Script', and that should stop the VM from suspending on its own. Taken from http://superuser.com/questions/377549/vmware-guest-pauses-when-the-host-is-idle-how-do-i-keep-it-running